# Server 2012r2 says "You need admin privilges to complete this task" but i am the admin

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, permissions

Simple small office with Windows Server 2012r2 (just the one server), three PCs.  No changes to this setup in *eight years* other than lovingly updated.

Suddenly when I RDP into it, it doesn't recognize that I *am* the admin.  Examples:

If I go to Task Manager to stop something, I get "Access Denied. You need Administrator privileges..."

Same if I go into dnsmgmt.msc. And many others, not least GPEDIT. And in the below screen cap fails either This Computer or The following computer:

[image]

All updates are current and (yes, bad me to some but that's another discussion) we don't run any antivirus on this box so zero non-Windows stuff on it or going on: 100% exists to share drives/folders to the client PCs.

Did my duty with Google and DDG and zip that remotely addresses this.

Other than Firefox and Chrome that have been installed since day one, only portable apps here: Notepad++, MalwareBytes.

Did have Emisoft Emergency portable just before, though, and only thing that is close to the date of this issue. Submitted a support issue but (imagine!) no reply.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a DC as well? If not, open up lusrmgr.msc and look at the group memberships. If your user isn't in the Administrators group, then you need to find one that is, you can always add/reset local users if you have to when you're not a DC and you have local access by editing the registry. Otherwise, if it's a DC, hopefully you've been smart and added other domain admins, and/or have the domain recovery key.

Comment: @SteveButler:  Yes, its a DC, it's a single server very small network.  Did check and the user is an Admin.  Did a reset on the password as a "why not, give it a shot".  I can access DNS via the server's  Active Directory Administrative Center "modern" interface and it allowed me to see what was in there but not change anything.  Here's where it gets weird: if I right-click a shortcut to DNS from desktop with Run As Admin, it works.  Same for Device Manager which said I'm logged in as a Standard User.  With Run As Admin, no warning or error.  What?!?

Comment: Something seems wonky about your UAC. what level is it set to?

Comment: @SteveButler: Off completely. Used
`New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force`

This server and 1 PC are exhibiting the same thing: not a UAC prompt but that it doesn't always recognize that the logged in user is an Admin.  Have to give rights to some folders that already have Admin rights (like where event logs are located).
Server's in us as-is since 2012 and the PC although new is a clone of the old one equipment.  Both exhibited this behaviour after a routine scan with Emisoft EEK.

Comment: I think you found your issue then. When all other variables have been eliminated, look for the common factor. Perhaps EEK is messing with your UAC settings, causing this nonsense. Many would argue that UAC is good security practice.

Comment: @SteveButler  Yes, I did mention EEK and have to conclude only possible factor remaining. Did submit a support request, albeit to their forum (which should get SOME response), bit crickets.  Thanks for following this and suggestions.  Here's mine: stick to Malwarebytes for just-in-case scans.